Problems when trying to render references (.bib file) in html format
I'm facing problems trying to render references (.bib file) in html format using Quarto.
The complete document is a book with six chapters and each chapter has its own reference section at the end, so that I have six .bib reference files (references_chapter1.bib, references_chapter2.bib etc.).
When I try to render the document I get an error message indicating some problem in the the reference file of chapter 5:
processing file: cap05.qmd
                                                                                                                                                                                            
output file: cap05.knit.md

WARNING: Warning: The computation used to determine source line information from the engine timed out.
Line number information will be unavailable and/or inaccurate.
Error reading bibliography file referencias_cap05.bib:
(line 1074, column 1):
unexpected end of input

Error position:

The complete content of my reference file is here.
I checked for formatting and spelling mistakes such as missing code delimiters { , = or even empty spaces, but I couldn't find any. All smalls adjustments I tried (deleting or inserting { , or spaces) did not solve the problem.
When I make small adjustments in the file content, the error message, most of the time, keep indicating a problem always in the last line and in the last character position or the file content, even when the indicated position has no characters inserted (as shown in the image above).
After posting I realized that my problem is a bit similar to the one addressed in the following related question "Quarto Render having diff of engine output timed out issue", except for the fact that he is running Python while I am running my analyzes in R. Despite that, I still haven't been able to see a way to solve my problem.

The problem was in the italic encoding used in some references in the .bib format {\textit{ }.
See an example below (highlighted in bold):
    @book{Pereira_2013,
    author = "Pereira, R. C. and Roque, F. O. and Constantino, P. A. L. and Sabino, J. V. and Uehara-Prado, M.",
    title = "Monitoramento {\textit{in situ}} da biodiversidade: Proposta para um Sistema Brasileiro de Monitoramento da Biodiversidade",
    publisher = "Instituto Chico Mendes de Conservação da Biodiversidade - ICMBio",
    address = "Brasília, DF",
    year = 2013 }

After removing this code from all references that contained it, the rendering process was successful.
See more information here.
